# HTML5 - Cross Browser Iframe postmessage - parent to child communication

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, postmessage

I wrote a content script that injects an iframe to any website (therefore different domain).

I need the parent website to send some information to the child iframe, however I couldn't find a way to do it.

The code

```
var targetFrame = $('#myIframe')[0];
targetFrame.contentWindow.postMessage('the message', '*');
```

Doesn't work somehow and i get a `Cannot call method 'postMessage' of undefined` error.
But then when I tried the same code directly in Chrome's console, it worked.

I had no trouble sending a postMessage from the child to the parent though but just need a way for the parent to send messages to the child iframe.

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote code that did `postMessage` to an `iframe` and I encountered quite a similar issue where it said `contentWindow` is `undefined`.

In my case, my `iframe` was not yet part of the DOM tree, it was a variable created by `document.createElement('iframe')`.

Once I put it hidden (width and height 0px, visibility hidden) into the body of the page, `contentWindow` was no longer undefined and everything worked as expected.

I found the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) page for `postMessage` extremely useful when I was working on my project.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the following library:

http://easyxdm.net/wp/

It doesn't require any flash/silverlight, only javascript. And it is compatible as far back as as IE6.

It took a little doing to get it up and running, but once it was things ran very smoothly.

Keep in mind that if the iFrame you're opening on the other domain uses a different protocol (HTTP vs. HTTPS) the browser will kick out a warning which prevents your script from running (unless the user says they will accept the risk). If you have access to both protocols it may be wise to host the contents of the iFrame on both HTTP and HTTPS and load the appropriate script accordingly.

Good luck!

Comment: This library requires Flash, which is no longer supported in many browsers.

Comment: @AndersonGreen It only uses flash for browsers that don't support postMessage in which cause we can assume that they support flash or will fail regardless...

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to target contentWindow.  Try this:

```
var targetFrame = $('#myIframe')[0];
targetFrame.postMessage('the message', '*');
```